# How to use Asciidoc for rules

Tags: jqassistant

The jQA doc shows examples where concepts and constraints are in Asciidoc files. I put also a constraint into an Asciidoc file which seems to be ignored by jQA. The directory is correct:
Reading rules from directory ...\jqassistant-plugins\doc\architecture
But there is no line
Adding rules from file ... bla.adoc
Do I have to configure somehow that adoc files should be read? And how do I declare the groups in Asciidoc files?
If I put an xml file with constraints into that directory, only the xml rules were executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem, created an [issue](https://github.com/buschmais/jqassistant/issues/274) and fixed it.Will be available with the next release.